# Issue revealing figcaption in Safari only

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, bulma, figcaption

I’m running into an interesting CSS issue on my portfolio site that I haven’t been unable to solve on my own. I’m using the  and  tags to transition from an image to a caption/button on desktop hover or mobile click. Unfortunately, it works on all browsers except for Safari iOS.

On my iPhone, I’ll click one of the images and it won't respond; but if I hold down on it, I'm then able to select the caption text which is seemingly there but not visible. I don’t experience this issue on any other mobile browsers that I've tried so far.

See [the “Projects” section of this page](https://kjmagill.com/#portfolio) from Safari iOS to attempt to duplicate the bug.

The specific lines of code regarding this issue can be found [here (HTML)](https://github.com/kjmagill/portfolio/blob/master/index.html#L351) and [here (CSS)](https://github.com/kjmagill/portfolio/blob/master/css/main.css#L1216).

Note that I used the [Bulma CSS framework](https://bulma.io) to create the site, and have since tried several manual changes/additions to the CSS for this section in an attempt to resolve the issue. No luck yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Please review [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is okj to link to external resources but all of the relevant code should also be included in the question. This should be included as a a [**minimal, reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).so we can see it in action and be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about that. Will add snippets in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `.overlay` `div` inside of `figure`. Because it span the entire width and height of the parent, it's blocking clicks (taps) on mobile and preventing `figcaption` from being revealed.

[image]

One way to fix this without `JavaScript` (the dream) is to add `tabindex="0"` on the `figure` element.

```html
<figure class="image is-3by2" tabindex="0">
```

Adding `tabindex` will allow the element to respond to `:focus`, removing the overlay when `figure` has been touched.

```css
.image.is-3by2:focus .overlay {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly, and I appreciate the explanation for why it does.